# Javascript asynchronous AJAX and recursive sequencing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, recursion

I have a situation where using synchronous ajax requests smell like cake.

Basically I need to figure out how can I sequence asynchronous requests so next ones wait, but the structure in what I need it made this quite challenging. I'll try to explain what I have and what I would like to accomplish.

1. A button is clicked
2. An AJAX request is sent to get a list of things that need to be done.
3. The list must go through a for loop, so steps go one-by-one.
4. Now's the tricky part. Some steps require additional ajax requests to fetch info on how to continue, but next steps can't continue while the previous one isn't done.
5. An even more tricky part is that one step might have a whole other sequence. Also some steps give prompts to the user and must wait for answers before continuing.

I will now try to explain my current structure.

1. initSequence(sequenceName, params); This function takes a name of a sequence, requests the list from the server and passes it to the next function:
2. runSequence(sequence, params); This function is the one that does the for loop. For each action in the sequence it does minimal checks and runs the action with the next function:
3. executeAction(actionName, actionArgument, params); This function basically is a motherload of code that knows when to do what based on passed parameters. This function can also launch another initSequence(); which will in theory make this a recursive behaviour.

What would be the ideal way to queue these requests? I've seen something about using promises. But did not manage to figure out how to chain them between different function calls or how does it work with recursion?

Any ideas and help will be appreciated.

EDIT: Probably completely working code:

```
var listf = ['print', 'ask', 'send', 'list', 'done'];
var lists = ['print2', 'ask2', 'done2'];

var promiseFor = (function(condition, action, value) {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if(!condition(value)) return;
    return action(value).then(promiseFor.bind(null, condition, action));
  });
  return promise;
});

var initSequence = (function(n) {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if(n == 1) {
      return runSequence(listf);
    }
    return runSequence(lists);
  });
  return promise;
});

var runSequence = (function(list) {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var count = 0;
    promiseFor(function(count) {
      return count < list.length;
    }, function(count) {
      return executeAction(list[count]).then(function(result) {
        return ++count;
      });
    }, 0).then(console.log.bind(console, 'for done'));
  });
});

var executeAction = (function(action) {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if(action == 'print') document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'Some text<br>';
    if(action == 'print2') document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'Some text 2<br>';
    if(action == 'ask') {
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'Alert 1 for pause<br>';
      alert('pausing');
    }
    if(action == 'ask2') {
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'Alert 2 for pause<br>';
      alert('pausing again');
    }
    if(action == 'send') {
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'Text after delay<br>';
        resolve(true);
      }, 2000);
      return;

    }
    if(action == 'list') {
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'Starting subsequence<br>';
      initSequence(2);
    }
    if(action == 'done') document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'Sequence done<br>';
    if(action == 'done2') document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'Sequence 2 done<br>';
    resolve(true);
  });
  return promise;
});

initSequence(1);
```

[Codepen link for the code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNygzv)

Comment: _synchronous ajax requests smell like cake._ & _The code samples can be either pure javascript or jquery._....what are you doing dear?

Comment: @Jai Maybe it came out wrong, I meant to say that someone who knows how something like this can be accomplished can write an example in either pure javascript or jquery syntax.

Comment: _What would be the ideal way to queue these requests?_ Use promise or deffered objects like `$.when()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use promises to chain requests and execution together.

```
var firstMethod = function() {
   var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      setTimeout(function() {
         console.log('first method completed');
         resolve({data: '123'});
      }, 2000);
   });
   return promise;
};


var secondMethod = function(someStuff) {
   var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      setTimeout(function() {
         console.log('second method completed');
         resolve({newData: someStuff.data + ' some more data'});
      }, 2000);
   });
   return promise;
};

var thirdMethod = function(someStuff) {
   var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      setTimeout(function() {
         console.log('third method completed');
         resolve({result: someStuff.newData});
      }, 3000);
   });
   return promise;
};

firstMethod()
   .then(secondMethod)
   .then(thirdMethod)

//... etc.
```

Here are some links to resources that might be helpful

https://html5hive.org/how-to-chain-javascript-promises/
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: Thanks for leading me to the correct direction, I think I managed to do what I needed to do. I've edited my question and added the code I came up with and a link to codepen if you're interested to see how it preforms.